# Can anyone explain the output of this java exercise to a complete beginner?

Tags: java

I am new to Java, and I am trying to understand the logic of the following code. Can anyone explain to me how

```
y = x - y;
```

gives the output `0 0 1 1 2 1 3 2 4 2`?

```
class MyFirstApp {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        while ( x < 5 ) {
            y = x - y;
            System.out.print(x + " " + y + " ");
            x = x + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about debugging it ?

Comment: @SURESH ATTA - I'm not sure this post is particularly appropriate (As it seems like homework, and does not show what he has done to try to solve it on his own). However I doubt a "complete beginner" would be able to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bust out the paper and pen/pencil in order to learn ow logic works in coding dude. I'll help you out this time though to get you started.

First time through

```
x = 0   y = 0
y = x - y = 0 - 0 = 0
x = x + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1
```

Second time through

```
x = 1   y = 0
y = x - y = 1 - 0 = 1
x = x + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2
```

Third time through

```
x = 2   y = 1
y = x - y = 2 - 1 = 1
x = x + 1 = 2 + 1 = 3
```

Fourth time through

```
x = 3   y = 1
y = x - y = 3 - 1 = 2
x = x + 1 = 3 + 1 = 4
```

Final time through

```
x = 4   y = 2
y = x - y = 4 - 2 = 2
x = x + 1 = 4 + 1 = 5
```

Going through logic like this is the best way to learn how it works within code in my opinion

Comment: Thanks ShadowManes for your feedback, as it shows me how output works. Thank you.

Comment: It's not a problem. Anytime you have a question about output just bust out the paper and pen then go through every step like it is written in the code. You'll learn a lot that way and it's a great thing to do as a beginner. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
while ( x < 5 ) {

    y = x - y;


    System.out.print(x + " " + y + " ");
    x = x + 1;
  }
```

As `x=0` this loop will be executed until `x>=5` and in every iteration the values of `x` and `y` will be printed. You notice that in the end of each iteration the variable `x` will be incremented. Thus the loop will execute 5 times.

Yielding :
the first iteration : x = 0 , y = x - y = 0 - 0 = 0, thus displaying `0 0`.
In the second iteration x = 1, y = x - y = 1 - 0 = 1, thus printing `1 1`
And so on